# jQuery which is faster function calls or if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, just recently I had been working with a script that was called on hover and mouse move. It was an image preview script. In the script I had 2 if-else statements and 2 if statements.

After I saw that, because there was a lot of redundancy in the code I decided that it would probably be best if I did some refactoring and outsourced it all to a function. But when I was done with the function I saw that I only really saved about 10 lines of code, and had 1 if-else statement and 2 if statements. So in my mind it is faster, but then I am not sure if the function call actually adds more overhead in the end.

Here is the code... everything that is commented out is what I initially had, but consolidated into a function called `pos`

Just curious to know which is actually faster, and which is better practice.

```
this.imagePreview = function(){ 
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 10;
        yOffset = 30;
        maxHeight = $(document).height();
        maxWidth = $(document).width();

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */

    $("a.imagePreview").hover(function(e){
        var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        img = img.substring(0,img.lastIndexOf("."));

        var height = $('#preview').height();
        var width = $('#preview').width();

        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $(".imagePreviewContainer").append("<p id='preview'><img src='"+ img +"pview.png ' alt='Image preview' /><span>"+ c +"</span></p>");

        pos(e, width, height, maxWidth, maxHeight, true);

/*      if((e.pageX + yOffset + width + 20) > $(window).width()){
            $("#preview")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX - yOffset - width) + "px")
                .fadeIn("fast");
        }
        else{
            $("#preview")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
                .fadeIn("fast");
        }

        if((e.pageY + yOffset + height + 50) > maxHeight){
            $('#preview')
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset - $('#preview').height()) + "px");
        }
        console.log("Page height : " + maxHeight);*/
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#preview").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.imagePreview").mousemove(function(e){

        var height = $('#preview').height();
        var width = $('#preview').width();

        pos(e, width, height, maxWidth, maxHeight, false);

/*      if((e.pageX + yOffset + width + 20) > maxWidth){
            $("#preview")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX - yOffset - width) + "px")
        }
        else{
            $("#preview")
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
                .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
        }
        console.log("Page height : " + maxHeight);

        if((e.pageY + yOffset + height + 50) > maxHeight){
            $('#preview')
                .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset - height) + "px");
        }*/
    });

};

var pos = function(e, width, height, maxWidth, maxHeight, fIn){
    var xOffset = 10;
    var yOffset = 30;
    var xChange = 0;
    var yChange = 0;

    if((e.pageX + width + 50) > maxWidth){
        xChange = width + yOffset + yOffset;
    }
    if((e.pageY + height + 60) > maxHeight){
        yChange = height;
    }

    if(fIn){
        $('#preview')
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset - yChange) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset - xChange) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");
    }
    else{
        $('#preview')
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset - yChange) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset - xChange) + "px");
    }
}
```

Comment: How about to measure it?

Comment: A few extra if statements are not going to make a difference unless you are doing expensive operations in the checks (which is not the case here). But the only way to figure out which is faster is [by measuring it](http://jsperf.com/).

Comment: @Laoujin so now how about as far as best practice? I would probably say creating a function is better.

Comment: I would go with the version that is, in your opinion, most readable / easiest to understand. If you notice a performance issue, then I would go about trying to optimize the procedure by measuring each optimization you try.

Comment: @Laoujin well, I just ran some tests in chrome and with the added if-else statement it took `15.000ms` and then with the function calls it took `9.000ms` so I guess there is my answer.